# How do you turn off zerolink on xcode 5?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I know this sounds stupid, but I have no idea how, and it is really bugging me. Where is the option to turn off zerolink on xcode 5? Same problem with other newbies, my little application won't run on other computers.

Answer (score 2):

Zerolink was removed in 2008 with the release of Xcode 3. If your compiled application does not run on other computers, your problem lies elsewhere.